# Problems parsing XML with lxml

Tags: python, xml, pandas, lxml, lxml.objectify

I've been trying to parse an XML feed into a Pandas dataframe and can't work out where I'm going wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import lxml.objectify
path = "http://www2.cineworld.co.uk/syndication/listings.xml"

xml = lxml.objectify.parse(path)
root = xml.getroot()
```

The next bit of code is to parse through the bits I want and create a list of show dictionaries.

```
shows_list = []
for r in root.cinema:
    rec = {}
    rec['name'] = r.attrib['name']
    rec['info'] = r.attrib["root"] + r.attrib['url']
    listing = r.find("listing")
    for f in listing.film:
        film = rec
        film['title'] = f.attrib['title']
        film['rating'] = f.attrib['rating']
        shows = f.find("shows")
        for s in shows['show']:
            show = rec
            show['time'] = s.attrib['time']
            show['url'] = s.attrib['url']
            #print show
            shows_list.append(rec)

df = pd.DataFrame(show_list)
```

When I run the code, the film and time field seems to be replicated multiple times within rows. However, if I put a print statement into the code (it's commented out), the dictionaries appear to as I would expect.

What am I doing wrong? Please feel free to let me know if there's a more pythonic way of doing the parsing process.

EDIT: To clarify:

These are the last five rows of the data if I use a print statement to check what's happening as I loop through.

```
{'info': 'http://cineworld.co.uk/cinemas/107/information', 'rating': 'TBC', 'name': 'Cineworld Stoke-on-Trent', 'title': "Dad's Army", 'url': '/booking?performance=4729365&seats=STANDARD', 'time': '2016-02-07T20:45:00'}
{'info': 'http://cineworld.co.uk/cinemas/107/information', 'rating': 'TBC', 'name': 'Cineworld Stoke-on-Trent', 'title': "Dad's Army", 'url': '/booking?performance=4729366&seats=STANDARD', 'time': '2016-02-08T20:45:00'}
{'info': 'http://cineworld.co.uk/cinemas/107/information', 'rating': 'TBC', 'name': 'Cineworld Stoke-on-Trent', 'title': "Dad's Army", 'url': '/booking?performance=4729367&seats=STANDARD', 'time': '2016-02-09T20:45:00'}
{'info': 'http://cineworld.co.uk/cinemas/107/information', 'rating': 'TBC', 'name': 'Cineworld Stoke-on-Trent', 'title': "Dad's Army", 'url': '/booking?performance=4729368&seats=STANDARD', 'time': '2016-02-10T20:45:00'}
{'info': 'http://cineworld.co.uk/cinemas/107/information', 'rating': 'TBC', 'name': 'Cineworld Stoke-on-Trent', 'title': "Dad's Army", 'url': '/booking?performance=4729369&seats=STANDARD', 'time': '2016-02-11T20:45:00'}
{'info': 'http://cineworld.co.uk/cinemas/107/information', 'rating': 'PG', 'name': 'Cineworld Stoke-on-Trent', 'title': 'Autism Friendly Screening - Goosebumps', 'url': '/booking?performance=4782937&seats=STANDARD', 'time': '2016-02-07T11:00:00'}
```

This is the end of the list:
...

```
{'info': 'http://cineworld.co.uk/cinemas/107/information',
  'name': 'Cineworld Stoke-on-Trent',
  'rating': 'PG',
  'time': '2016-02-07T11:00:00',
  'title': 'Autism Friendly Screening - Goosebumps',
  'url': '/booking?performance=4782937&seats=STANDARD'},
 {'info': 'http://cineworld.co.uk/cinemas/107/information',
  'name': 'Cineworld Stoke-on-Trent',
  'rating': 'PG',
  'time': '2016-02-07T11:00:00',
  'title': 'Autism Friendly Screening - Goosebumps',
  'url': '/booking?performance=4782937&seats=STANDARD'},
 {'info': 'http://cineworld.co.uk/cinemas/107/information',
  'name': 'Cineworld Stoke-on-Trent',
  'rating': 'PG',
  'time': '2016-02-07T11:00:00',
  'title': 'Autism Friendly Screening - Goosebumps',
  'url': '/booking?performance=4782937&seats=STANDARD'},
 {'info': 'http://cineworld.co.uk/cinemas/107/information',
  'name': 'Cineworld Stoke-on-Trent',
  'rating': 'PG',
  'time': '2016-02-07T11:00:00',
  'title': 'Autism Friendly Screening - Goosebumps',
  'url': '/booking?performance=4782937&seats=STANDARD'}]
```

Comment: `print(show_list)` - maybe you have data multiple times in show_list ? maybe there are data multiple times in xml ?

Comment: use more `print` to see what happend. You use `append` inside `for` loop so you probably add the same `rect` with then same `name` but with different `title` or with the same `title` but different `time`.

Comment: you only have one `title` and `time` keys in your dictionary, don't you intend to have multiple entries? (you are overwriting the key on each pass)

Comment: @salparadise My thinking was that the use of dictionaries would mean that individual times of a particular film at a particular cinema would appear in different dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only has one object that keeps getting updated: `rec`. Try this:

```
from copy import copy
shows_list = []
for r in root.cinema:
    rec = {}
    rec['name'] = r.attrib['name']
    rec['info'] = r.attrib["root"] + r.attrib['url']
    listing = r.find("listing")
    for f in listing.film:
        film = copy(rec) # New object
        film['title'] = f.attrib['title']
        film['rating'] = f.attrib['rating']
        shows = f.find("shows")
        for s in shows['show']:
            show = copy(film) # New object, changed reference
            show['time'] = s.attrib['time']
            show['url'] = s.attrib['url']
            #print show
            shows_list.append(show) # Changed reference

df = pd.DataFrame(show_list)
```

With this structure, the data in `rec` is copied into each `film`, and the data in each `film` is copied into each `show`. Then, at the end, `show` is added to the `shows_list`.

You might want to read [this article](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/) to learn more about what's happening in your line `film = rec`, i.e. you are giving another name to the original dictionary rather than creating a new dictionary.

Comment: That's excellent. Thank you. I've had similar problems with copies in numpy and pandas, but thought I could simply set the values of a new dictionary with the data of the old one. Clearly not.